# Call custom Class' obj of type NStimer into viewController

Tags: ios, xcode, nstimer

In the sample tutorial I found, I noticed a timer made using NStimer class: it was implemented directly into viewController.m 
I tried to make it as "separate" obj class in it's own timer.m and relative header.
This is what i got

```
#import "Timer.h"

@implementation Timer

-(void) startTimer{
    seconds = 31;


myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(subtractTime:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
  NSLog(@"%i",seconds);
}

-(void)subtractTime: (Timer*)myTimer{
    seconds--;

    NSLog(@"seconds %i",seconds);

    if (seconds == 0) {
        [myTimer invalidate];

    }
}

@end
```

According to the output in NSLog, the countdown itself works perfectly; my issues start when i try to display it into a label using the form label.text = into the viewController.m
(here's just the method implementation part)
(Xcode gives me no error bout @implementation part both in Timer.h and viewController.h, also project build runs ok but the countdown into the label is locked to 0)

```
-(void)setupGame{

count = 0;
scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score:\n%i",count];//these strings are to make a score label increasing of 1 every time a button's pressed

Timer *newTimer = [[Timer alloc]init]; //i create a new obj of my Timer class
[newTimer startTimer];
[newTimer subtractTime:(Timer*) myTimer]; //i set the methods i created
timerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",seconds]; //??? i don't know which var put here, actually, i cannot get here the refreshing seconds to make timerLabel changing
NSLog(@"newTimer %@",myTimer);//just a try to see this output, it's not what i need of course

}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here.  Firstly make `Timer` an instance variable of the view controller as when you do this:

```
-(void)setupGame{

    // blah
    Timer *newTimer = [[Timer alloc]init];
    // blah
}
```

The `Timer` object will be destroyed when this method returns, as the object goes out of scope.

The second problem is that you need to update the UI control when the time changes, so perhaps pass a reference to the UI control (`UILabel` or whatever it is), and store this as an instance variable of the `Timer` class, so the timer object can update it itself.

In this particular case I don't see the value of a separate `Timer` object as it would be easier to implement what you want just within the view controller class.

Answer (score 0):

As Trojanfoe says, you are over-complicating this. Make your view controller create the timer and be done with it.

If you are bound and determined to create a custom class to manage a timer then you have a bunch of work to do.

I would NOT pass the label to the Timer object, as that breaks the encapsulation of the view controller. You should always treat a view controller's views as private to that view controller.

Instead, here's what I would do:

You need to add a Timer instance  variable to your view controller, as Trojanfoe says.

You need to define a TimerProtocol. In that protocol, define a "timerFired" method, that would include the remaining time value as a parameter. You probably also want a "timerFinished" method

When you create a Timer object, set yourself up as the delegate of that timer.

Rewrite your Timer object's subtractTime method to send a message to the delegate with the remaining time value. Then in the view controller's timerFired method, update the label.

In your view controller's timerFinished method, nil out the instance var to the Timer object so it will be deallocated, since you then done with it.

Again, this is an over-complicated solution that does not add any value. The only reason to do it this way is as a learning exercise, but it is not a good design decision.

Comment: Thank you, btw i decided to go straight to the point; as exercises it didn't look so useful